# Is the 0.3% French tax on French securities (including U.S ADR) applicable to sales as well?

Tags: taxes, fees, france, transaction

Investors may get an unpleasant surprise when they invest in French stocks, even those listed overseas like U.S. The U.S ADRs of French companies are affected as well. There is a French Transaction tax of 0.3%. **Is this hefty tax applicable to the sales of French securities as well?** So, there will be a total transaction tax of 0.6%?

One more question. **How can an investor whether a U.S ADR is a French company from its name?** It will be good to place French securities on a lower priority due to this 0.3% French Transaction tax. There are plenty of alternatives elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot tell by the name but here's a pretty good list that's reasonably up to date:

http://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=geo_france

Should be noted, the French tax applies to positions held over night, not daytrades. The Italian tax applies to both.